# How to transfer files from windows to Ubuntu instaled on VMware?

Tags: vmware, virtualization

I have Installed [Backtrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/)(an Ubuntu based linux) on VMware and I have a file on main host(win 7) which I want to send to this virtual machine. What should I do?

Comment: Note that we don't support unofficial derivatives of Ubuntu on this site. If more backtrack questions come up, you might want to post on our sister-site [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 ways 2 transfer file from windows to Linux (backtrack)

1 . install ssh on backtrack and on windows Install filezilla 
 then u can transfer file from windows to backtrack

2 . install vmware guest tools & poweroff backtrack & share folder in Vmware 
as shown in pic 
[image]

add folder from your windows & that will be Shared

now in start backtrack & login

in terminal

```
mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ /mnt/hgfs/
```

the shared folder will be in /mnt/hgfs/

**Through ssh on backtrack (if not installed )**

```
 sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

then edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
set "PermitRootLogin" to "yes".
```

save & exit

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart

then ifconfig > check the ip address
```

then from windows open filezilla

[image]

in host type the ip address of backtrack user name root password "toor" (if not changed)

& then u can transfer file from windows to backtrack

Comment: I tried sharing folder. I got an error while executing mount command: "Error: cannot mount filesystem: No such device". I'm using VMware Workstation 7 on Windows seven. I installed vmware tools according to this picture. http://technopolis.ir/uploads/backtrack-vmware-tools.jpg

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-share-folders-with-your-ubuntu-virtual-machine-guest/